# SharePoint MasterPage :: Oslo and Seattle

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have tried to Google the results between these master pages :: Oslo and Seattle available in SharePoint, but to no results. Can somebody help me in understanding the difference between the two?

Thanks.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the only difference is their page layout and navigation. Seattle is what we're used to from 2010, and Oslo is new, moving the left nav to the top, and removing the top navigation all together. Oslo has a wider layout for your content.

Comment: David's answer is correct. They are both metro styles, but oslo has the content area floated in the centre of the screen and floating navigations to the right and top of the page with an extra navigation area to the right.

Comment: There's another difference, Oslo handles anonymous users differently. Check it out: http://davidlozzi.com/2013/09/25/theres-more-than-meets-the-eye-differences-between-sharepoints-oslo-and-seattle-master-pages/